# How do I keep updating a variable's value?

Tags: c++

I was trying to write a code that will tell me the exponential growth using the unit amount of time (round) and population (pop) but ended up with a code that calculates value from the original variable. For example, when I input 10000 for pop and 3 for round, it should first calculate the the %5 of 10000, add it to original value, then calculate again with the new value for 2 more times. I cannot seem to find a way to update pop everytime the for loop is repeated. Can someone help me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int pop, new_people;
    int i, round;

    cout << "Population: ";
    cin >> pop;
    cout << "Round: ";
    cin >> round;

    new_people = (pop * 5) / 100;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= round; i++) {
        pop += new_people;
        cout << pop;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You update `pop` every time, but you don't update `new_people`.

Comment: `new_people = (pop*5)/100;` is executed 1 time total. This is a one time assignment not a fomula that gets reevaluated each time you look at `new_people`. `c++` does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the new_people updation inside the for loop so that it gets updated each round.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int pop, new_people;
int i, round;

cout << "Population: ";
cin >> pop;
cout << "Round: ";
cin >> round;


for(i = 1; i<=round; i++){
    new_people = (pop*5)/100;
    pop += new_people;
    cout << pop;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, but the output hasn't changed

Comment: I think the output has changed, it's just that since neither your original code nor this answer's code separate each round's output with whitespaces or newlines it's hard to tell at a glance because the first several digits are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can put "new_people = (pop * 5) / 100" and "pop += new_people" in cycle so as to update the value of "new_people" and "pop".

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int pop, new_people;
    int i, round;

    cout << "Population: ";
    cin >> pop;
    cout << "Round: ";
    cin >> round;

    for (i = 1; i <= round; i++) {
        new_people = (pop * 5) / 100;
        pop += new_people;
        cout << "round" << i << ": " << pop << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually does the job, thanks a lot!